# IS SQL Server 2008 Free With Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have installed Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 on application server running on Windows server 2012, after installing i see that SQL server 2008 was also installed along SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Is this SQL server 2008 and below mentioned components License Free?

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (64-bit)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Browser
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Common Files
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database Engine Services
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database Engine Shared
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 RsFx Driver
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
- SQL Server 2008 R2 SSRS Add-in for SharePoint 2010

Regards,
Sai

Answer (score 1):

No SQL Server 2008 is not part of SP Foundation 2010. are you sure it is installed along with SPF 2010 installation?

SQL Server is not free and you need to have a license for it.